# Cant make multiple sprite using 'for' loop in Haxeflixel

Tags: for-loop, sprite, haxe, haxeflixel

I want to make the same sprite be created as many times as there are values ​​in "iteraktList". Let's say iteraktList is equal to two sprites. But the sprite is created only once and in the last sprite that was added

```
for (i in 0...iteraktList.length) 
{
    what = new FlxSprite(iteraktList[i].x + (iteraktList[i].width / 2) - 10, iteraktList[i].y - 30).loadGraphic(Paths.image('spooky/what'));
    what.visible = false;
    what.setGraphicSize(Std.int(what.width * 2));
    add(what);
}
```

So i do this and thats dont work BUT i try to make 'what' sprite 'I' times like this:

```
for (i in 0...iteraktList.length) 
{
   what[i] = new FlxSprite(iteraktList[i].x + (iteraktList[i].width / 2) - 10, iteraktList[i].y - 30).loadGraphic(Paths.image('spooky/what'));
   what[i].visible = false;
   what[i].setGraphicSize(Std.int(what[i].width * 2));
   add(what[i]);

}
```

And an error popped up

```
Array access is not allowed on flixel.FlxSprite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i in 0...iteraktList.length) 
{
    var what = new FlxSprite(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I then have to show 'what' when the player comes to an item in iteraktList

`
if (checkInteracteble())
{
     what.visible = true;
}
`

Comment: Need more info or code.
What is iteraktList? Could you store reference on what in iteraktList[i].
Or create array and push what to it